# Copying several files in R from network

Tags: r

I was passing some files(like 1.2 million pictures) from a network folder to my pc, the thing is that at some point(like at 95% of the copying) it fails and now I have only 1.1 million of pictures. I decided to set the difference between what I have and the original folder" so I tried:

```
setwd(C:/Users/yo/Desktop/fotos/tmp)
x <- list.files()
y <- list.files("\\\\10.90.111.68\\folder\\fotos\\tmp")
z <- setdiff(y,x)
```

and then I tried to use this

```
file.copy(from=z, to="/Users/yo/Desktop/fotos", copy.mode = TRUE)
```

but then I got this error(result)

```
[961] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [969] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [977] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [985] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [993] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 108383 entries ]
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

it would be great if you can tellme how to copy the difference from network, in advance thank you all

Comment: Hi, is your `z` object an url ?

Comment: You got a result not an error.

Comment: how do i make z an url? even if it were a url, how do i copy just the files in the difference? thank u for awnsering

Comment: ok NelsonGon, no error, just not working as i would like any suggest to make it work as i wish?

Comment: what's the output of `warnings()` ?

Comment: errors on the networks paths i guess is the first coment problem jeje i have no the log of the errors i close the Rstudio let me  reproduce it